# How to show image in jsGrid from database using javaScript/JQuery/Hibernate/Spring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, hibernate

I am trying to display image in the jsGrid from the database.I have tried below code.
.js code:

```
fields : [ {
    title : "Currency Code",
        name : "curr_code",
        type : "text",
        width : 35,
        filtering : false,
        editing : true,
        align : "center"
    },
    .....
    {
        title : "Symbol",
        name : "curr_symbol",
        type : "text",
        width : 35,
        filtering : false,
        editing : true,
        align : "center"
    },
    {
        type : "control",
        editButton : true,
        modeSwitchButton : true,
        deleteButton : true,
        width : 35
    } 
]
```

Grid View:

```
$.post('../../setupController/currencyGridView', function(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var currList = {
            "curr_id" : obj[i].currency_id,
            "curr_code" : obj[i].curr_code,
            "curr_desc" : obj[i].curr_desc,
            "curr_count" : obj[i].curr_country,
            "curr_symbol" : obj[i].symbol,
        }
        $("#currencygrid").jsGrid("insertItem", currList).done(
            function() {
            });
    }
});
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/currencyGridView", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Currency> currencyGridView() {
        List<Currency> currList = setupDao.currencyGridViewData();
        return currList;
}
```

Now its showing output like this[image: Jsgrid view] but not showing the image..

Answer (score 2):

You can use itemTemplate. If you have image link you can do something like below

```
    { 
    title: "Symbol",
    type: "text",
    width: 50,
    itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
        if(item.symbolId){
            return '<img src="/img/"'+ item.symbolId + '" "width="42" height="42">';
        }
        return '';
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can override the **itemTemplate** function for that image column.

`js
itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
    return value;
},`

Or do some custom row rendering : http://js-grid.com/demos/custom-row-renderer.html